# Selecting object with mouse - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseclick-event

I know that the question has already been asked. I want to be able to change the color of an object if selected with the mouse. I tried writing the code myself but it seems not to work, so I guess that I am missing something. That's basically the script:

```
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2 );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xcccccc, 1 ); 
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        scene.add(camera);

        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices.push(
            new THREE.Vector3( -5,  5, 0 ),
            new THREE.Vector3( -5, -5, 0 ),
            new THREE.Vector3(  5, -5, 0 )
        );
        var face = new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2);
        geometry.faces.push(face);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x3300ff});
        var triangle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(triangle);

        camera.position.z = 10;

        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown );

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {    
            event.preventDefault();
            var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,   
                                    -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,  
                                    0.5 );     
            var projector = new THREE.Projector();                                        
            var raycaster = projector.pickingRay( mouse3D.clone(), camera );
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
            }
        }

        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        };

        render();
    </script>
```

If someone could help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: use eventcontrols ) http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/controls_events_piano.html

Comment: Let me remind you that raycasting is done on CPU and is exceptionally slow. Better approach can be found by keyword "gpu picking": you'd like to render your scene with each clickable face having different color, and then just get a color of pixel by mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated your code and made [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLfrrkfx/2/)

In onDocumentMouseDown added

```
var raycaster =  new THREE.Raycaster();                                        
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse3D, camera );
```

instead of

```
var projector = new THREE.Projector();                                        
var raycaster = projector.pickingRay( mouse3D.clone(), camera );
```

To objects array added triangle mesh and updated size of the renderer.
I suggest you to start using Console and do some debugging. You can easily find these errors yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain a little why I should use those stuff and why we add the triangle to objects. Also why is this `console.log(intersects)` in the code?

Comment: [Raycaster documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster), converts 2D mouse coordinates to the 3D world. Casts a ray from 3d mouse position, following the direction of the camera, and checks if hit any object on the way. Objects array is to check for intersection with the ray and we want to check if triangle is selected. console.log was for debugging, you can remove it. [JavaScript console in different browsers](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: @uhura Please attach a snippet