# Drag an object in combination with OrbitControls

Tags: javascript, three.js

**EDIT:** I've decided to not use DragControls or TransformControls as both are not doing what I require them to do. For now I've added a pivot Object3D at the cueball's position and made cue (stick) a child of that, and try to make my own mousehandler to rotate, and to pull back the stick.

---

I'm creating a Pool game in ThreeJS as a school project ([GitHub Source](https://github.com/diamundo/poolgame)).
I currently have the following meshes:
 - a table
 - a set of balls on their starting position
 - a cue (stick).

To rotate the scene, I am using [OrbitControls](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls) from [ThreeJS](https://threejs.org/docs/).

I also have a raycaster in place with which I can click on the cue (using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955103/selecting-object-with-mouse-three-js)).
Now, I want to keep the OrbitControls ability to rotate the world, but I also want to use the ability to rotate the cue around the white ball to shoot.

What I have in mind:
 - use an onDocumentMouseDrag() something to detect if I'm clicking on the cue and if so, to where I'm dragging it (rotated)
 - In the same function, see if the cue was dragged backwards and then "hit" the white ball with that vector.

Can you help me achieve this?

See below for my "main".js: [GitHub: Poolgame.js](https://github.com/Diamundo/Poolgame/blob/master/poolgame.js)

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xcee0ff);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var objects = []; //for raycaster

//Table
var pooltable = new PoolTable();
scene.add(pooltable);

//Lighting
scene.add(new BarLighting() );

//ambient light
scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x909090 ) ); // soft white light

//Balls
var poolballs = [], ball;
for(var i = 0; i<=15; i++) {
    ball = new PoolBall(i); 
    scene.add(ball);
    poolballs.push(ball);
}

var cue = new PoolStick();
cue.position.copy(poolballs[0].position);
cue.rotateZ(- (100 / 90) * Math.PI / 2); //10 degrees above table
scene.add(cue);
objects.push(cue);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown );
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {    
    event.preventDefault();
    var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,   
                            -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,  
                            0.5 );     
    var raycaster =  new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse3D, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        console.log(intersects[0]);
        //has found intersect, i.e. we clicked something: the stick.

    }

} // end of onDocumentMouseDown

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    controls.target.copy(poolballs[0].position);
//  controls.target.copy(pooltable.position);
    controls.update();

    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
}

camera.position.x = -150;
camera.position.y = 120;
camera.lookAt(pooltable.position); 
controls.update();

render();
```

Comment: Maybe [this three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_spline_editor.html) will give you some ideas for your school project. Sorry, I can't help you with your code.

Comment: @WestLangley You got me in the right direction! I went looking for it's documentation and found [this](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_transform), and it's rotation is exactly what I need.

Comment: Be wary of [this issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12630).

Comment: I will, thanks. Had already experienced it myself, so I know what you/they mean.